# Get current timestamp from a specific timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to get a timestamp from a specific timezone that is independent of the local time.

I want my clients from all over the world to see the exact same timestamp. Is this even possible? I don't want a solution in node.js but if there is a working library, please include it.

Comment: use moment.js library  https://momentjs.com/ and https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: I've already tried it, I guess I'm using the wrong code then. Are you sure it's not just for node.js?

Comment: Something like UTC time? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp

Comment: its a javascript library and i a have used it in  many applications, say for example in angularjs frontend application

Comment: Okay, thanks. Do you have a sample code that would work?

Answer (score 1):

You can either generate a timezone independent timestamp by means of JavaScript, using `Date` object, or using specialized libraries such as [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```js
const timestampMilliseconds = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log(timestampMilliseconds);

const timestampSeconds = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
console.log(timestampSeconds);

const timestampSecondsMoment = moment().unix();
console.log(timestampSecondsMoment)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get different moment().unix() result on my PC in Sweden, and my VPS located in France.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use `moment.utc().unix()` instead of `moment().unix()`? I would also verify that OS date & time is configured correctly on both hosts.

Comment: No it didn't make a difference. And the date and time is correct on both hosts. Isn't it possible to just pick a specific timezone and get the same timestamp on both hosts?

Comment: It's possible to create a date in a specific timezone by using [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) however, I doubt that it will help, since unix timestamps are timezone independent (therefore converting two dates in different timezones into unix timestamps should produce equal result).

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to get a timestamp for a "specific time zone". If you know what the time zone offset is for that specific time zone then you should be able to get a UTC date, subtract the time zone offset from it and output a date string that should be the same on all clients. This statement should work:

```
var timeZoneOffset = 300; // Eastern Standard Time
var sameDate = (new Date(((new Date()) - (timeZoneOffset * 60 * 1000)))).toISOString()
```

`new Date()` should return the same time in milliseconds on all clients if the date and time of the local machines are accurate. Time zone offsets are in minutes so you need to multiply them be 60 * 1000 (60 seconds/minute times 1000 milliseconds/second) and then subtract that many milliseconds from the UTC date to get it to equal the current time in the time zone that has that offset. Then convert it to an ISO string. You can manipulate the resulting string if you want. Perhaps get rid of the Z on the end.

```
var dateWithoutZ = sameDate.slice(0,-1);
```